# A Question about a sort of 'future in the past' usage

Tags: tenses

I hear this use of "would" many times when recapping a sporting event and was wondering what tense this would be, and if the usage is even proper.

The following describes events that happened in a game earlier in this day:

"In the fifth inning, Smith would homer and Jones would follow with a triple.  The pitcher would strike out the next three batters, and so the Dodgers would get out of the inning without further damage."

Comment: It's entirely proper if it occurs in the context of a past-tense narrative, and the use is exactly as you describe it: a futurive use of *will* cast in the past-tense form to signal that the eventualities  occurred after the 'Reference Time' of the narrative in which it is embedded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to describe the future in the past](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/how-to-describe-the-future-in-the-past)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is proper; it's called Future in the Past. While the example you provided could easily be reworded to just use normal past tense (i.e. "In the fifth inning, Smith homered and Jones followed with a triple."), there are cases in which Future in the Past is the only concise way to explain something. For example: "I was going to pick up milk at the grocery store, but I forgot about it."

In the past, "picking up milk" was an event in the narrator's future. But in the present, "picking up milk" never happened. It would be very difficult to express this without the Future in the Past tense.

[Here's some more information on Future in the Past if I haven't already bored you to death.](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html)