# Is this sentence grammatically correct? I grew up in Paris, after I turned 18 I would go to Barcelona

Tags: grammar

Is the use of 'would' in this sentence correct :"I grew up in Paris, and after I turned 18 I would go to Barcelona"?

Comment: i just want to know if  i't is correct to  write the sentence with "would"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to describe the future in the past](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/how-to-describe-the-future-in-the-past)

Comment: It's correct in some contexts.  I'd lay odds that it's not correct in the context where you intend to use it, however.

Comment: is correct in this context: Imagine you’re reading an autobiography, and the narrator who is now 60 says “I grew up in the country, and After I turned 18, I would go to London"?

Comment: "...I would go to London (and live there for the next five years)" OR "...I would go to London (whenever there was an interesting concert at the Albert Hall)"?

Answer (score 3):

It would be possible for an autobiography to say "Consider my 18th birthday. I had grown up in Paris and soon I would go to London", as a future past tense.  This particular usage does not even require that the condition was fulfilled: "I knew that when I turned 18 I would go to university. Sadly, when we lost all our money, the plans changed."

You seem, though, to be asking only whether *would* can be used as an alternative to *did* without changing the meaning; the answer is "No".

Answer (score 0):

In this sense, "would" implies a future conditional action; the condition being "turned 18." The tenses are mixed in the second part of the sentence. For example, "grew up in Paris" (past tense) and "would go to Barcelona" (conditional future). This is fine, it makes sense to the reader, however I feel it is more grammatically correct to say:

"I grew up in Paris. After I turned 18, I went to Barcelona."

 
Without knowing the context of the sentence though, it is difficult to understand what sense you are trying to achieve.

Comment: here is the context Imagine you’re reading an autobiography, and the narrator who is now 60 says “I grew up in the country. After I turned 18, I would go to London"